# Windows 8.1 - ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path for ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Trying to develop app on windows using ionic framework. By following this link:http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

I'm facing this problem while working with the ionic cli.

Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path: E:\Primary Insatalations\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk; Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.

[image]

This my app details

cmd : >ionic info

> Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
>   Ionic Version: 1.2.4
>   Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
>   OS: Windows 8.1
>   Node Version: v5.7.0

FYI:
No problem with ANDROID_HOME. I configured it in the system variable.

```
E:\IonicProject\myapp>echo %android_home%
E:\Primary Insatalations\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk;
```

Comment: Did you mean to make your Android_Home go to E:\Primary Installations\ ... you have Instalations - misspelled.

Comment: Do you try set `ANDROID_HOME` path variable without blank space? Just change `Primary Insatalations` to `Primary_Insatalations`. Hope this will help, regards!

Comment: @刘文壮 Still I got the same error.

Comment: @SteveKennedy I have set an environment variable for Android_Home. For Ionic again do I need to set an Android_Home manually by using CLI?

Comment: I was just pointing out that you misspelled the word installations, in hopes that was the issue.

Comment: No.. @SteveKennedy I created folder name as Insatalations not installations. After removing blank space and again I set environment variable this is my ANDROID_HOME = E:\PrimaryInsatalations\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I resolved My issues by removing semi-column in android-home at Environment variable.

[image]